# How to go back when I run :Ex command in Vim

Tags: linux, vim

I editor a text file with Vim. then I run :Ex command.

now, I want to go back to re-edit this text file but didn't want to exit vim.

what should I do?

Comment: You could try [`:bunload`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bunload) to unload current buffer & go back to previous

Comment: Sorry the question is really unclear. Could you detail what you are doing (what commands you've entered, keys you've pressed, and whether you want to abandon any changes brought to the file). Thanks. From what I've understood I would however suggest to try `:vi` to go back to normal mode, but I'm not sure that this is what you're asking for.

Comment: Did you `:w`rite the file before `:Ex`ploring? Do you have `set hidden`? Does it show up when you `:ls` buffers?

Answer (score 4):

Type <kbd>Shift-q</kbd> to enter `Ex` mode.
Type **`visual`**(or **`vi`**) to go to `Normal` mode.