# How to back to editing file after :Ex

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm editing a new file in NeoVim and I don't remember the path of the directory I want to save my file to, so I want to look at the directory tree before saving. I do this by typing :Ex, which takes me to Netrw.

I'm done looking at the directory tree and I want to go back to my file and and finish my work. However I don't know the command to get back from Netrw to the file, and none of the numerous solutions I looked up online worked. The help file didn't help either. The intuitive command would be :q, which works fine for help but doesn't work for this situation. I have also tried q, Q, gq, gQ, :visual and :vi as suggested by people online.

Comment: @BobMorane No, as mentioned.

Comment: Note that Netrw can be opened in its own window with `:help :Vexplore` or `:help :Sexplore`, which would allow you to take a look at the directory structure without leaving your current buffer.

Comment: @romainl Yeah, thanks. There's apparently like a dozen different permutations of the :Explore command. An added benefit of using it that way is that :q actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, after making this post I finally stumbled upon a working solution in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292697/how-to-go-back-when-i-run-ex-command-in-vim#comment11718812_9292697) by [another.anon.coward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925381/another-anon-coward) on [How to go back when I run :Ex command in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9292697)

> You could try [:bunload](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bunload) to unload current buffer & go back to previous

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just press `Ctrl-6` to go back to the previous buffer. Also check the nvim help: `:help CTRL-6`.

Comment: Ctrl-6 can be useful in other situations but it doesn't work in the described scenario, at least not in my nvim setup.

Comment: Weird. Works for me. Can you try `Ctrl-^` instead? Also, which terminal are you using?

Comment: I can't type Ctrl-^ because of nordic layout so I can't say anything about that. I use powershell most of the time as unfortunately I'm bound to windows for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use those default vim mappings for that:

- `CTRL-O` - Go to older cursor position in jump list
- `CTRL-I` - Go to newer cursor position in jump list

So when you'll be at netrw press `<C-o>` couple of times and it will bring you back to the place where you started.

To read more about jump commands: `:help jump-motions`